# GemFire regions : partition vs distributed regions?

Tags: gemfire, in-memory-data-grid

when reading about gemfire regions, i found that there are 4 types of regions, local (data is accessible only by the member that defines it), replicated (data is replicated accross the members), but i didn't found the differenced between distributed and partition regions ... 
Is the difference between them that partition regions distribute data fairly between members and that's not the case for distributed regions ?

Answer (score 1):

Partition regions allow you to scale up to having a lot more data than replicated regions.

With a replicated region, every member has an entire copy of the region locally.

With a partitioned region, the data is split into *buckets* which are distributed among the members. So you can each member only holds part of the data.

You might find the descriptions of replicated and partitioned regions in this gemfire tutorial useful:

http://gemfire81.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/getting_started/gemfire_tutorial/running_tutorial.html